# How to getPaths() with geoXML3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, geoxml3

I had more than 600 `kml` files to load in a single google map.
Initially I tried with `KmlLayer()`, but it didn't work due to the amount of `kml` files, so I found `GeoXML3`, and it works really fine.

Now I need to retrieve the path's coords for every polygon created with GeoXML3. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Polygon) I found the method `getPaths()` that seems to be just what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work because now I don't create polygons using the class `Polygon` but using the class `geoxml3`

```
for (i=0; i < controlli.length; i++)
{   
    appo = kmlurl + controlli[i].id + ".kml";
    appo = appo.replace(" ", '_');
    area[controlli[i].id] = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        zoom: false,
    });
    area[controlli[i].id].parse(appo);
    //here I would like to do something like: 'area[controlli[i].id].getPaths()'
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The google.maps.Polygon objects created by geoXml3 to represent the KML polygons can be accessed 2 ways:

1. `area[controlli[0].id].docs[0].placemarks[0].polygon.getPath()`

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u9vLemsq/1/)

2. `area[controlli[0].id].docs[0].gpolygons[0].getPath()`

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u9vLemsq/)

where geoXml is a reference to the parser object (your `area[controlli[i].id]`)
and i is a sequential reference to the placemarks (or the polygons) in the KML).

If you are using it on a KML file loaded asynchronously, you need to wait for the `parsed` event, or use the data in the `afterParse` function.